# How to interpret the fact $P(\limsup A_n) \ge \limsup P(A_n)$

Tags: probability-theory

The proof is easy. I want to know what are some interpretations of this fact. Here is what I thought.

$P(\limsup A_n) =$ the probability of the events(collection of elements) that appears infinitely often;  $\limsup P(A_n)$= the upper limit of the probability of events $A_n$.

Then how to understand $P(\limsup A_n) \ge \limsup P(A_n)$?

Answer (score 4):

$P(\limsup A_n)$ is the probability that infinitely many of the $A_n$ occur. If $\limsup(P(A_n)) = a$ that means (roughly) that there are infinitely many events that have probability $a$. So at any point in the sequence, there is at least probability $a$ of another event occurring. Thus the probability of infinitely many events is at least $a$.

This matches up to the line
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{k \geq n}A_k\right) \geq \sup_{k\geq n}P(A_k)
$$
in the proof, where you then take limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ to get the theorem.